# Microsoft Excel -- Images distorted when printing

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, printing, distortion, emf

### Images get distorted; circles print as ovals

I have an Excel document which has several images (vector art, EMF images).

When printing, the images are distorted: circles become ovals, which looks ridiculous.

Surprisingly, it doesn't matter which printer driver I use:  `Adobe Acrobat DC Save to PDF`, or Microsoft's built-in `Save to PDF/XPS`, I get exactly the same distortion.

This should be a 0.7" diameter circle, as shown printed using Adobe Acrobat DC and Microsoft Excel's built-in PDF feature:

> [image: Screenshot of PDF produced using Adobe Acrobat DC PDF driver]
> [image: Screenshot of PDF produced using Microsoft Excel built-in PDF printer]

That is not a circle!

## I have tried:

- Resize the images externally so they can be maintained at 100% scaling in the document

Is there something that I can do, short of moving to a desktop publishing app?

- Microsoft Excel Professional Plus 2016
- Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.928]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has a LONG, LONG standing problem with graphics in that it reduces their size, changing the aspect ratio along the way, by about 10%. Which seems to be approximately what you are experiencing.

There is no solution.

If you want things "right", you have to see what a given graphic does, then edit it to change its sizing so that after reduction it is what you desired.

Unfortunately, that only helps the printed version. Now you've adulterated it, the onscreen version will look wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can try to export an exact output to PDF, with no distorted image. Changing font theme worked for me.

Under the **PAGE LAYOUT** tab,
on Theme panel, select Fonts, choose **Corbel** font theme.

Print your document or save as PDF. There you go!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I wasted a lot of time sorting the same, and I finally made it fixed in my VBA code. It needs to be adjusted the height before printing to PDF, so its height is increased by 6%, then printed (at that moment it is fine), and then again decrease the image height back to the original height.

If you are interested in the VBA code I created to automate it, you can have a look to my blog:

https://j4.kopl.pro/news/printing-to-pdf-from-microsoft-excel.html

Available for anyone who needs to sort the same.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1185503)

Comment: @Toto: I believe the answer is present in my reply (the image height adjustment and its value). The link leads just to the code, which might not be required, if the user will change the image dimensions manualy before the printout to PDF, however I understand your point.