# Solving the 20 year old "Microsoft Excel distorts images when printing" bug

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, fonts, images

There are many posts about this on the internet. Here are a few:

- [SU] [Microsoft Excel -- Images distorted when printing](https://superuser.com/questions/1648364/microsoft-excel-images-distorted-when-printing)
- [Images distorted when previewing or printing from Excel - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/images-distorted-when-previewing-or-printing-from/86705c7b-ce88-4689-8729-a15448be6d59)

The gist is, you put a perfect square picture on an excel spreadsheet, you get a vertically squished rectangle when you print. The workaround is to have distorted images on the page and then they print properly. This bug hasn't been fixed in 20 years.

There are 2 reproducable ways to fix it

1. Images with oneCellAnchor do not distort! But images with twoCellAnchor do!

I haven't found any official MS office explanation for these, but you can read about it here on the openofficexml site:

- http://officeopenxml.com/drwPicInSpread-twoCell.php
- http://officeopenxml.com/drwPicInSpread-oneCell.php

This has been proven to work. Take a picture that was distorting on print, edit its anchor from twocell to onecell, put a new `drawing1.xml` into the xlsx file and reopen it and the picture will no longer distort!

2. Changing the fonts will stop pictures from distorting

**Source**: Excel will not print images at correct height/width!! @ [ExcelForum](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/889534-excel-will-not-print-images-at-correct-height-width.html)

For me I haven't found Metro but Corbel or manually choosing Segoe UI in there worked. But for some reason, changing all cells to Segoe UI didnt! Only setting it in the fonts menu (and I could change back to Calibri everywhere and it still worked)

AND IT KEEPS THEM TWO CELL ANCHORED!

I think we're really close to solving this once and for all. So I'm asking for help. Maybe someone has also experimented with this or knows Excel in and out better than me.

Questions left to asnwer:

1. What does setting font in the "page layout" actually change? What changes if font is set as "Segoe UI" but every cell font is still Calibri?
2. How can you make Excel anchor pictures with oneCellAnchor? It seems changing a single picture property (like "lock aspect") immediately transforms it to twoCellAnchor and it starts distorting again?

Comment: One question per post please, so that we can give one good answer that can be marked correct. Also, while this isn't a bad question, the TYPE of question is probably a better fit for a forum, where open discussion is the primary point.